# Corner bead cement covering

Tags: bathroom, shower

Recently I've renovated a bathroom in my house. I re-tiled the shower and there was extra cement on the wall after the bullnose was put in.

I wanted to cover the cement so I could just paint the wall up to the bullnose so it looks clean. I tried caulking it thinking that would work. It ended up looking like it melted when it was drying so I'm in the process of removing the half dried caulk.

Is there a better/easier way to cover this cement? It's about a half inch wide.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to sand it down. Tile mortar is fairly soft and a common sanding block should do. Be careful not to scratch your tile (mask it if you like). Skim it with drywall joint compound if that doesn't yield satisfactory results, then sand it again.

Next time, either be more careful troweling the mortar or apply masking tape to the wall first. You don't have to have mortar right to the very edge of the bullnose. In fact, you're better off leaving it back slightly so you can grout against the wall and have a clean look without mortar showing through.